# Android Studio - Can't manually resize buttons

Tags: android-studio, button

For some reason I can't manually resize any buttons on the design view using the handles. I can click and drag the handles but when I release, no changes are seen anywhere.

EDIT:

Here is the xml for the button:

```
<Button
        android:text="√"
        android:id="@+id/button15"
        android:background="@drawable/operator_style"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#707070"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonLog"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonLog"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button8"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
/>
```

And the linked background "operator_style" xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#00C7FC" />
            <stroke
                android:width="4dp"
                android:color="#9FEDFF" />
            <corners
                android:radius="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#cccccc" />
            <corners
                android:radius="0dp" />
            <elevation
                android:elevation="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: remove 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
from the xml file in the button tag

Comment: If I do that the button disappears from the layout. The object has NOT been deleted though.

Comment: post your xml file

Comment: so on my screen it doesn't disappear but shows the tick mark , what layout are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think it's the relative layout but I don't know how to check/change that in android studio.

Comment: just open the xml file it shold be mentioned inside it

Comment: Can confirm, it's using relative layout.